# function to confirm the presence of both letters and numbers/ Ignoring excedents

Tags: string, matlab

So, I'm trying to build up a program with MATLAB according to some indications from my teacher and I came up with some obstacles which would give me a better grade if I could get them right. Here they are:

1. The user is asked to insert a string but it can't have more than 20 characters. If it does, the excedents will be ignored and the string is saved with the first 20 characters the user inserted. How do I ignore the excedents in a string and save it anyway?
2. `isletter` is a function that tells us if the elements are all letters. In this program, the user is asked to insert a string that needs to include both numbers and letters, so that strings with just letters or just numbers are excluded, and then I'll use a while to keep asking for a string with these characteristics.

Could you please help me? This is my first semester with MATLAB. Thank you!

Comment: Is it specified what should happen if the user enters any characters that are neither letters nor numbers, like '/@!' or whitespace?

Comment: In that case, the password (what the user is creating) is not accepted and the user is asked to insert a valid password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to disallow characters other than letters and numbers (i.e. `'/@!'` or whitespace) and require that the string they enter has to have at least 1 letter and 1 number, then you can use the [ISSTRPROP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isstrprop.html) function (which is more general than [ISLETTER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isletter.html)) to check for other types of characters. The idea to use [INPUTDLG](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/inputdlg.html) to prompt for the string (as suggested in [Aabaz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8592180/52738)) is a good one, so here's a nice condensed solution using INPUTDLG that achieves what you want:

```
answer = '';  %# Initialize answer to be an empty string
while any(~isstrprop(answer, 'alphanum')) || ...  %# Check for alphanumeric chars
      ~any(isletter(answer)) || ...     %# Check for at least 1 letter
      ~any(isstrprop(answer, 'digit'))  %# Check for at least 1 number
  answer = inputdlg('Enter string:');   %# Prompt for input
  answer = answer{1}(1:min(20, end));   %# Trim answer to max of 20 chars
end
```

Note how the functions [MIN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/min.html) and [END](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/end.html) are used to trim the string to 20 characters.

Comment: Nice answer, `isstrprop` is really the adequate function for this.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your problem you can use the Matlab function `inputdlg` which prompts a dialog box asking for user input. Then you can trim the input as you like.

For the second part of your problem the function `isletter` that you mentioned will tell you for each character individually if they are alphabetic letters, so you could sum that result and check if it is between 1 and 19 for example. That will tell you that your string contains both letters and numbers.

Finally, you can put your code inside a while loop and change a variable when your conditions are met so that you can break outside of the loop.

This example code demonstrates this:

```
tryagain=1;
while(tryagain)
answer=inputdlg('Insert a 20 character string that contains both letters and numbers','User input');
answer=answer{1};
if(numel(answer)>20)
    answer=answer(1:20);
end
letters=sum(isletter(answer));
numbers=sum(~arrayfun(@(x)isempty(str2num(x)),answer));
if(letters>0 && numbers>0)
    tryagain=0;
end
end
```